# How to set keepalive in node js mongo db(outbound connection)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, keep-alive

Please help me out how to implement keepalive in nodejs mongodb. As I am using mongo do outbound connections from node js

How to validate the keepalive is working or not.

Please help me if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/connection) given by MongoDB states about different connection operations. For implementing a keep alive, you need to use the `keepAlive` option in the connection URI.

```
// Connection URI
const uri = "mongodb+srv://sample-hostname:27017/?keepAlive=true";
```

This will enable keepAlive on the TCP socket.

If you want to have a delay before initiating keepAlive on the TCP socket, you can use the `keepAliveInitialDelay` option in the URI. The `keepAliveInitialDelay` should be of an integer type.

```
// Connection URI
const uri = "mongodb+srv://sample-hostname:27017/?keepAlive=true&keepAliveInitialDelay=30000";
```

Comment: this no longer works for mongodb version 5?