# First connection to MongoDB always fails

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, docker

I'm using mongoDB(5.0.0) in a docker container with a spring backend, timeout set to 72 hours.
When I try to do a save I will get the following error ONCE:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-22T12:16:46.986+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn477","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"10.0.17.9:53868","uuid":"a5fb01f8-d7ba-42d1-bf37-d8d46207cd05","connectionId":477,"connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-22T12:16:46.985+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn485","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":35811620}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-22T12:16:46.985+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn485","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"10.0.17.9:55974","uuid":"34870a6d-7017-4239-adaa-b4e17b87f814","connectionId":485,"connectionCount":3}}
```

Afterwards I am able to continue as expected, save works and no errors until I leave it alone for a while and try again later, then I get the same error pop up.

This is our connection string: mongodb://::27017/?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&connectTimeoutMS=2000&maxIdleTimeMS=259200000

Anything I'm forgetting? Thanks!

- Tried to increase timeout
- Tried to move mongoDB in its own docker container

Comment: I think is related more to the keep alive than the timeout. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65153899/how-to-set-keepalive-in-node-js-mongo-dboutbound-connection#:~:text=For%20implementing%20a%20keep%20alive,keepAlive%20on%20the%20TCP%20socket.)

Comment: I've set it now, I'll have to monitor this over the next 24 hours to see if the issue pops up again. Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing. let me know how it goes. Also, I'd suggest you to set the timeout to lower values